# Point in Polygon function for MySQL

Tags: mysql, latitude-longitude, point-in-polygon

I have GPS information stored in multiple MySQL tables structured like the following:
*(Running MySQL Server version 5.5.43 on Ubuntu Server 14.04.1)*

event_number, time, latitude, longitude
1, 12:52:50, 40.5401, -86.5715
1, 12:52:51, 40.5404, -86.5707
1, 12:52:52, 40.5406, -86.5699
1, 12:52:53, 40.5409, -86.5691
1, 12:52:54, 40.5411, -86.5683
1, 12:52:55, 40.5414, -86.5676
2, 13:22:35, 40.9723, -85.1755
2, 13:22:36, 40.9726, -85.1759
2, 13:22:37, 40.9728, -85.1762
2, 13:22:38, 40.9731, -85.1766
2, 13:22:39, 40.9734, -85.1770
2, 13:22:40, 40.9737, -85.1773

Each table represents a separate vehicle with hundreds of separate "trips" within each table.
 The goal is to find lambda for a Poisson distribution by testing how many vehicles arrive in a boundary box per hour. While there are several algorithms for determining whether a point is inside a polygon, I'm only concerned with the initial time at which the vehicles enter the boundary area.
I'm open to any suggestions. Ideally I would like to create a function in MySQL that will give me a count of the vehicles entering the boundary area per hour.

Comment: Can a vehicle exit the box and re-enter it?  If so, does this count again?

Comment: Are you using MyISAM, and does the table have a `SPATIAL` index?

Answer (score 0):

The first time a vehicle is in the polygon is

```
SELECT MIN(time)
    FROM tbl
    WHERE IsInPoly(latitude, longitude);
```

(Where IsInPoly is whatever function works.  If you have a `SPATIAL` index, then a function is available in MySQL; I don't have the specifics off hand.)

If you need the "first time for each `event_number` when the vehicle is in the polygon":

```
SELECT MIN(time)
    FROM tbl
    WHERE IsInPoly(latitude, longitude)
    GROUP BY event_number;
```

These queries will probably involve table scans, so they won't be fast.

Comment: Thanks Rick, unfortunately I don't have a SPATIAL index. I'm using InnoDB, which I understand supports spatial data but not indexes on them. I'm beginning to think PHP might be a more viable solution...